# How to calculate day max for time series along with relevant hour?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a dataframe with some timeseries inside. It has 3 columns: day, hour and value:

| day | hour | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12-Jan | 11-00 | 14 |
| 12-Jan | 12-00 | 100 |
| 12-Jan | 13-00 | **345** |
| 12-Jan | 14-00 | 195 |
| 13-Jan | 12-00 | 76 |
| 13-Jan | 13-00 | 221 |
| 13-Jan | 14-00 | 102 |
| 13-Jan | 15-00 | **395** |

As you see max value for 12 Jan is observed at 13-00.

I want to calculate max of the "value" for each "day". I can do it via simple

```
df.groupby("day")["value"].max()
```

It works, but after grouping apparently we have hour information erased. The question is : how can I build dataFrame which would contain day max value *along with the hour when that value was observed*, i.e.

| day | hour when maxValue was observed | maxValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12-Jan | 13-00 | 345 |
| 13-Jan | 15-00 | 395 |

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

I created a sample of your `df`:

```
         day   hour  value
0 2021-01-12  11-00     14
1 2021-01-12  12-00    100
2 2021-01-12  13-00    345
3 2021-01-12  14-00    195
4 2021-01-13  12-00     76
5 2021-01-13  13-00    221
6 2021-01-13  14-00    102
7 2021-01-13  15-00    395
```

And run this code on it:

```
res = pd.merge(df.groupby('day').agg({'value':'max'},as_index=False).add_prefix('max_'),df,how='left',left_on='max_value',right_on='value')
```

And got back:

```
   max_value        day   hour  value
0        345 2021-01-12  13-00    345
1        395 2021-01-13  15-00    395
```

Comment: Thanks, sophods! I guess you meant .transform("max") instead of .transform("sum").

Comment: This works for me, though my initial request was to create a dataset grouped by day which has a dayMax and hour when that maximum occurred.

Comment: Yes I meant 'max', apologies. In your description you specify: "want to calculate max of the "value" for each "day", that's why I thought that. Sorry help me understand here, you also want the max hour and the max value per day? Or you want the max value per day and per hour?

Comment: I need max value per day along with the hour when that value was observed. Please see the table in the answer, this is exactly what I need. For example, for 12-Jan we observed maximum value = 345 and observation was made at hour = 13-00. Sorry for misleading description.

Comment: Actually my final goal is to get distribution of day maximums by hour.

Comment: So then basically I guess you want to do the same thing, but just change 'value' with 'hour'.  ```df['maxHour'] = df.groupby('day')['hour'].transform('max')``` ? By the way, it would help if you could provide an actual sample of your dataset and not just the desired output.

Comment: Actually this would always yield last hour of the day.

Comment: Dataset example added, notice that it matches the desired result in 2nd table. Sorry for misleading description again.

Comment: I edited my answer now. This should be it now :)

Comment: Thank you, sophods! Thats it.